# incorrect img link by .extract() - scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to extract the "src" link from the image, but the return obtained by ".extract ()" or "extract_first ()" collects a different link than the one obtained by the browser.

Domain:
https://www.udacity.com/course/aws-cloud-architect-nanodegree--nd063

tag and Link img src in the browser:

```
<img _ngcontent-iridium-us-c29="" class="image" irdeferimage="" alt="Tom Verbiscer" src="//www.udacity.com/www-proxy/contentful/assets/2y9b3o528xhq/2l5ESfrrZ3WbOCqGKriWr3/94f34988a58419ac17c493d80ab7759d/Thomas_Verbiscer100x100.jpg" srcset="//www.udacity.com/www-proxy/contentful/assets/2y9b3o528xhq/2l5ESfrrZ3WbOCqGKriWr3/94f34988a58419ac17c493d80ab7759d/Thomas_Verbiscer100x100.jpg 1x">
```

The xpath query:

```
print(response.xpath('//*[@id="section-1Dv0cQsQhvDKCIdU6hpW0B"]/ir-canonical-degree-instructors/div/div/div/ir-horizontal-scroller/div[1]/div[1]/img/@src').extract())
```

Query return:
['/assets/iridium/images/shared/placeholder.png']

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Start a Scrapy shell via `scrapy shell "https://www.udacity.com/course/aws-cloud-architect-nanodegree--nd063"`and then type `view(response)` and you will see what Scrapy "sees". Indeed the expected images are not there, only placeholders with the size of 1 px. Those will be replaced probably via Javascript/Ajax with the image-urls that you are trying to scrape.

Comment: Thankx @carpa_jo!